# Prove the following using a direct proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(p \vee q) \wedge (p \rightarrow m) \wedge (q \rightarrow m) \rightarrow m$

Do I have to do a proof by case if I want to prove this directly?

If m is true, then the right hand side and the left hand side is true? That's it? How do you pick the right variable when there are like 10 variables though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can argue like this:

$$\begin{align*}
(p\lor q)\land(p\to m)\land(q\to m)&\leftrightarrow\Big((p\lor q)\land(p\to m)\Big)\land\Big((p\lor q)\land(q\to m)\Big)\\
&\leftrightarrow\left(\Big(p\land(p\to m)\Big)\lor\Big(q\land(p\to m)\Big)\right)\\
&\qquad\quad\land\left(\Big(p\land(q\to m)\Big)\lor\Big(q\land(q\to m)\Big)\right)\\
&\overset{*}\to\Big(p\land(p\to m)\Big)\land\Big(q\land(q\to m)\Big)\\
&\to m\land m\\
&\leftrightarrow m
\end{align*}$$

The starred step follows from two applications of $(r\lor s)\land t\to r\land t$.

Comment: is that a direct proof though? aren't we supposed to assume the left side is true?

Comment: @Gladstone: It starts with the hypothesis and grinds through to the conclusion; it doesn’t use contradiction, or prove the contrapositive. In my book that makes it a direct proof. The only problem might be if you have some very specific definition of *direct proof* that you’re using, rather than the usual notion.